# Dump command list (Mac Terminal)

Tags: macos, terminal

A week ago, a friend sat down and tutored me through using Git. It was really helpful, and I cannot remember 60% of it. However, my Mac terminal remembers the history of the commands, which would fill in most of what I forgot.

It's all there. I can press 'up' to cycle through the history. Is there a way to dump this out to a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `history` command will output your command history. Combining with `grep` (a la `history | grep git`) should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't realise it was so obvious, I feel quite silly now! Will accept this when the cooldown is off.